# Convert Class Probabilities of a multiclass model to scores in range 0-100

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, probability, logistic-regression

What I want to do is to generate a score of 0-100 based on the predictions of a three class classification model.
For eg. The predict_proba of a 3 class logistic regression model gives me 3 probabilities x, y, z as shown below -

0   1   2

x    y   z

Now, I want to generate a score of 0-100 based on these probabilities, where 0 is closer to class 0 and 100 is closer to class 2.

Comment: Hello!! Even I have a similar problem.. Did you find solution for this?

Comment: Yes. I have found a workaround to do this. Right now, I am dividing my 0-100 scoresin 3 bins i.e 0- 32, 33-66, 67-100. Now, if the probability of class 1 is the highest the score would be between 33-66. Now, it would be towards 33 or 66 will depend upon the probabilities of other 2 classes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
prob['P']=(prob['1']*1+prob['2']*2)/2
```

prob['0'] is multiplied by 0, so you don't need it.

examples:

prob['0']=0.5, prob['1']=0.5, prob['2']=0==>prob['P']=0.25

prob['0']=0.75, prob['1']=0.25, prob['2']=0==>prob['P']=0.125

prob['0']=0.1, prob['1']=0.2, prob['2']=0.7==>prob['P']=0.8

prob['0']=0, prob['1']=0, prob['2']=1==>prob['P']=1

Comment: Hey Roee, this approach works fine. But, it would be great if you have some mathematical justification for this. Moreover, there are some cases for which it fails. For eg when we have probabilities as 0.34, 0.33, 0.33 for 0, 1 and 2 respectively. I expect a score in the range (0,35) for this but I get around 49 for this.

Comment: Think of it as weighted arithmetic mean - the weight is the class magnitude. if you have equal probs - you will get a score around 0.5 - this makes sense since you are in the middle between 0 and 100 - no class is strong enough.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Weighted arithmetic mean sounds quite fine, but why are we then keeping the denominator as 2. It must be 3. Shouldn't it?

Comment: Since the probabilities always sum to 1, this is a special case - usually, you divide by the sum of the weights, in this case, you divide by one. The division by 2 is a normalization. The maximal value will be obtained when you multiply a-100% chance by the value of 2 - this means you have to divide it by 2 since it's the maximal score.